# Is it possible to to rsync only files and passwords without .conf files

Tags: linux, hosting, rsync

Alright so here's the situation.

I wanted to setup a high-availability load-balanced cluster for my 2 linux servers but i realised that was a little bit out of my reach. So i decided to do something similar to save me some work.

So the plan is, i have a server hosting web, ftp and mails called : mars
I have copied the whole server to a new one with similar specs called : higgs

So now i'm going to change all the configuration files to use the proper IP and hostname, and i will change my MX entries on my GoDaddy to use higgs instead of mars. So the plan is that mars still does web but will be able to do mail if higgs goes down and vice-versa. So i want to do daily cronjobs that do rsyncs for my Web files, FTP files, and Mail files but also the password files if possible while excluding .conf files. Is there a way this is possible?

Comment: That must be possible. Where there's a will there's a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rsync is ridiculously powerful. If you just need to exclude `*.conf` files, you can call rsync with the `--exclude` flag like this:

```
rsync -a mars: higgs: --exclude='*.conf'
```

I prefer to keep my excludes in a separate file under version control, then reference that from the rsync command. Your exclude file (rsync_exclude.txt) might look like this:

```
*.conf
/home/fake_dir_to_exclude
```

Then call rsync like this:

```
rsync -a mars: higgs: --exclude-from=rsync_exclude.txt
```

One other helpful thing for debugging rsync is the `-n, --dry-run` flag combined with `-v, --verbose` flag. When called with these, rsync will spit out a file list without transferring anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this actually lowers my burden by quite a bit :P Could i use this to copy the content of mars to higgs?